# undefined reference to `_imp__ptw32_push_cleanup' when cross-compiling with pthreads using MinGW in Linux

Tags: c++, pthreads, mingw, cross-compiling

I am attempting to set up cross-compiling for a cross-platform, open source computer game (Simutrans-Experimental: a fork of Simutrans).

It uses the pthreads multi-threading library. At one part of the code, my fork (but not the original version) uses the pthread_cleanup_push() and pthread_cleanup_pop() functions.

When I attempted to cross-compile this (for 32-bit Windows using MinGW32), I got the following compiler error:

```
error: second operand to the conditional operator is of type âvoidâ, but the third operand is neither a throw-expression nor of type âvoidâ
 pthread_cleanup_pop(1);
```

(And a similar error for the "push" equivalent).

I was advised by one of the developers of the standard version of Simutrans to modify a part of pthread.h to

```
 #define pthread_cleanup_pop(E)\
(*pthread_getclean() = _pthread_cup.next, ((E) ? (_pthread_cup.func((pthread_once_t *)_pthread_cup.arg)) : (void)0));}
```

This then allowed the code to compile.

However, I now get linker errors relating to the same part of the code:

```
===> LD  build/mingw/simutrans-experimental
```

build/mingw/simworld.o:simworld.cc:(.text+0x1914): undefined reference to `_imp__ptw32_push_cleanup'
 build/mingw/simworld.o:simworld.cc:(.text+0x198b): undefined reference to`_imp__ptw32_pop_cleanup'
    collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
common.mk:21: recipe for target 'build/mingw/simutrans-experimental' failed

I do not understand what is happening here, or why the pthreads that comes with mingw does not work with one of the fundamental parts of the pthreads library.

Can anyone assist? I should be very grateful.

Comment: Did you have a look on http://www.mingw.org/wiki/pthreads_library ? Looks like Simutrans is relying on sourceware.org pthreads-win32 (on Win32 plateform).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The problem is not that the wrong path is specified for pthreads (which I think is what the link is about: it is not immediately apparent exactly what the link is about). There would be far more errors in the code if the path was wrong (and I know this because there was a time when the path was wrong and there were huge numbers of errors).

Apologies if I have misunderstood what you meant, incidentally, but it is not clear to me exactly what the relevance of the link to this specific issue.